# combine multiple pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple DataFrames that have the same format. I want to create a dataframe that combine the previous ones. each row of the result dataframe is a row of one of the previous dataframes where a certain column is the maximum,

Example

```
data1 :   
Name            Age
0   michael     18
1   lincoln     20
2   theodore    84
3   alexandre   95

data2 :   
Name            Age
0   sayed       17
1   hurley      29
2   sawyer      44
3   John        15

data3 :   
Name            Age
0   walter      50
1   jesse       15
2   fring       20
3   saul        34
```

the expected result would be:

```
Results :   
Name            Age
0   walter      50
1   hurley      29
2   theodore    84
3   alexandre   95
```

I have more than 500.000 rows and 51 columns i'm looking for something faster than just parsing all the data (O(n2) of complexity is so big)

thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a certain column is maximum'?

Comment: I don't understand how hurley and theodore get into the expected result, and why isn't sawyer there? So I think you need to elaborate on the selection process.

Comment: @Utsav in my dataframe i have a column named 'P' 'probability confidence' i want to take the row with this column is the max.

Comment: @amquack it's based on the row index. for index 1 we have licoln hurley and jesse with values 20, 29, 15. since 29 is the max we took hurley.

Comment: I see, so you want to append the dataframes, then do a groupby on the index to grab the max, similar to this answer: stackoverflow.com/questions/15705630/get-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-in-groups-using-groupby

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` to choose the max value between column of dataframes. Then apply this to all columns of dataframe. At last use `reduce()` to apply on all dataframes.

```py
import functools

columns = df_.columns

df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

def choose_larger(df1, df2):
    m = df1['Age'] > df2['Age']
    for col in columns:
        df_[col] = np.where(m, df1[col], df2[col])
    return df_

# Another possible function
def choose_larger2(df1, df2):
    m = df1['Age'] > df2['Age']
    m = pd.concat([m]*len(columns), axis=1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, df1, df2), columns=columns)

df_max = functools.reduce(lambda df1, df2: choose_larger(df1, df2), [data1, data2, data3])
```

```
print(df_max)

        Name  Age
0    michael   18
1    lincoln   20
2   theodore   84
3  alexandre   95
```